# I keep on getting this Error as I am trying to change the label text from a different View

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, fatal-error

any help is appreciated.
I am new to Ios development and I am trying to change a label text which is located in my first initial view controller. I want this text to change as I press a button in the second view controller which is segued to the initial one.

here is my first view controller

```
import UIKit

protocol gameModeDelegate {
    func didTapChoice(test:String)

}

class ViewController2: UIViewController {
    var selectionDelegate:gameModeDelegate!

    @IBAction func chooseButton(_ sender: Any) {

        selectionDelegate.didTapChoice(test: "TEST")

        let selectVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VC1") as! ViewController

        present(selectVC,animated: true,completion: nil)            

    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad() 
    }
}
```

here is what i have done in the second where the label is

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
            let selectVC2 = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VC1") as! ViewController2
            selectVC2.selectionDelegate = self

            winningLabel.isHidden = true
            winningLabel.center = CGPoint(x: winningLabel.center.x, y: winningLabel.center.y - 400)
      playAgainoutlet.isHidden = true
            playAgainoutlet.center = CGPoint(x: playAgainoutlet.center.x, y: playAgainoutlet.center.y + 400)
    }
extension ViewController: gameModeDelegate{
        func didTapChoice(test: String) {
            CommunicationLabel.text = test
        }



    }
```

I tried these two methods so far and i keep getting this error.

Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: This is because the view has still not loaded and you label will be nil at this time so it is giving error

Answer (score 0):

You should not use this approach to achieve the result, you may use two different approaches to achieve the same result.

1- Use a delegate protocol approach:
in **secondViewController** you should declare a protocol like this

```
protocol applySelecction {
    func applyText(text: String)
}
```

and in the class declare a variable like this.

```
var delegate: apply selection?
```

then in the button action

```
@IBAction func saveButtom(sender: UIButton){
    //print(selected)
    delegate?.applySelection(text: text) //text is the value select from UILAbel o the option the user select
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

then in **firstViewController** conforms to applySelection protocol like this

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController,applySelection{
func applyText(text: String){
   //update the UIlabel here
```

2- Use a closure.
here in **secondViewController** you should add a new var like this,

```
 var applyText: ((String) -> Void)?
```

then in

```
@IBAction func saveButtom(sender: UIButton){
    self.applyText(text) //text is your text to update
}
```

and in **firstViewController** in prepare for segue rewrite like this.

```
let vc = segue.destination as! fisrtViewController)
            vc.applyText = { [weak self] data in
                guard let self = self else {return}
                self.text = text //this is assigning the text to self-text supposing text is a UILabel in this viewController                    
            }
```

You may try one of the two approaches which may seem right for you.

**EDIT**.

try this.

```
 class ViewController2: UIViewController {
        var selectionDelegate:gameModeDelegate!

    @IBAction func chooseButton(_ sender: Any) {

        selectionDelegate.didTapChoice(test: "TEST")
        //if segue is a show segue
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
       //else is a modal segue.
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad() 
    }
}
```

PD. you dont have to present a viewcontroller already present in the view stack, only dissmis it. Good luck

Comment: I tried your first approach and even a different it's just refusing to work

Comment: sorry, i was oof for a weak i dont have time to read SO, but looking your  post i guess your missing something, why the delegate call. explain wich is the firstViewController and wich is hte second.